# how to escape the pipe character in grep?

Tags: shell, grep, escaping, pipe

I have a file in this format:

```
coupait ||| eastern ||| 0.045454545454545456 2.718 ||| 0-0 ||| 
instaurer ||| characteristic ||| 5.797101449275362E-4 2.718 ||| 0-0 |||
tiendrait ||| fails ||| 0.005 2.718 ||| 0-0 |||
```

and I would like to search for a pair of words that are saved in two variables and which are seperated by |||. 
I tried many alternatives in vain like :

```
grep "$word1 ||| $word2 |||" $file
```

I tried escaping the pipe characters like this:

```
grep '$word1 \|\|\| $word2 \|\|\|' $file
```

How can I match the pipe in the file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `grep -F` - the variables will be interpreted by the shell and replaced with their respective values, then the quoted string (including the pipes) will be interpreted as a fixed string. Example:

```
$ cat file.txt
coupait ||| eastern ||| 0.045454545454545456 2.718 ||| 0-0 ||| 
instaurer ||| characteristic ||| 5.797101449275362E-4 2.718 ||| 0-0 |||
tiendrait ||| fails ||| 0.005 2.718 ||| 0-0 |||
$ word1=coupait
$ word2=eastern
$ grep -F "$word1 ||| $word2 |||" file.txt
coupait ||| eastern ||| 0.045454545454545456 2.718 ||| 0-0 |||
```

Comment: Putting the search term in Quotes was working for me. Thanks.

Comment: I definitely recommend `-F` option, in order to easily escape all kinds of characters inside a pattern. And here, I quote the definition that you might find when doing `man grep`:
`-F
Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings (instead of regular expressions), separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched. ` In my opinion, extremely friendly, and beautiful :).